# function click with selenium without id

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want know how I can click a button in this page [here](https://yopmail.com/it/) with selenium the code I try is this

```
import selenium 
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
PATH= "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://yopmail.com/it/")
inputsSI= driver.find_element_by_class_name("md").click()
print(inputsSI)
sleep(100)
driver.close()
```

the error I get is this:

> Message: element not interactable

Answer (score 0):

It's because `find_element_*` methods will return the first occurrence of the element they find. If you see the HTML page there is another `div` element before the button that has this `"md"` class and of course it is not the button you are looking for.

You are looking for this buttun :

```html
<div id="refreshbut">
    <button class="md" style="border-radius: 20px;"
            title="Controllare la posta @yopmail.com"
            onclick="{if(chkl())go()}"><i
            class="material-icons-outlined f36">&#xe5c8;</i></button>
    <input type="submit" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

It is wrapped inside a div with id of `"refreshbut"`.

So all you have to do is first get this div by id. Then search for the element which has the `"md"` class which is indeed the button you are looking for. (you could also get the button with XPATH. it's up to you)

like:

```py
inputsSI = driver.find_element(By.ID, "refreshbut") \
    .find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "md") \
    .click()
```

**Note 1**: It's better to use raw-string for your `PATH` variable.

**Note 2**: I would put the `driver.close()` statement inside the `finally` block so that it always runs

Comment: can you write me the code i must insert is like DivButton=driver.find_element_by_id(refreshbut).click i don't understand how i can write it

Comment: @oneperson please let me know if that solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

To click on the md button use button.md as a selector then wait for the element to be interactable. I don't know what goes in there so I just added a send keys of a.

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,30)                                 
driver.get("https://yopmail.com/it/")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#login"))).send_keys('a')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.md"))).click()
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```